# How do I sum a sequence of matrices?

Tags: r, matrix

so say I had a matrix

```
> A<-matrix(c(5,1,3,5,6,6,7,8,5),nrow=3,ncol=3)
> A
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    5    5    7
[2,]    1    6    8
[3,]    3    6    5
```

and I wanted to take the sum of i from 1 to 3 multiplied by each corresponding column.

so like

```
for (i in 1:3){
i*A[,i]
something 
}
```

then there is more code after this that I cant seem to figure out however simple it may seem, goal is to sum 1* first column + 2* second column + 3* 3rd column using some sort of iterative loop with i.

Comment: Use `A %*% 1:3`.

Comment: @eastclintw00d, can you explain that and post it as an answer?

Comment: This solves the problem thank you but I am more after the logic behind how its done iteratively so I can apply it to my problem rather than just copying the code. This is just a random example.

Comment: This is matrix multiplication. Have a look at examples in https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/matrix-in-r-arithmetic-operation-matrix-multiplication-and-difference-betwee/

Comment: I understand how to multiply them, I am looking for solving this problem via a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for a `for` loop version, maybe you can try the code below

```
s <- 0
for (i in 1:3) {
  s <- s + i*A[,i,drop = FALSE]
}
```

such that

```
> s
     [,1]
[1,]   36
[2,]   37
[3,]   30
```

---

As mentioned by @eastclintw00d in the comment, a simple way is using matrix multiplication

```
> A%*% 1:3
     [,1]
[1,]   36
[2,]   37
[3,]   30
```

Comment: I was looking for a loop like this thank you! does the drop=false part mean dropping vectors that are not the given ith column in each iteration?

Comment: @123123 `drop = TRUE` means that, if any of the dimensions has length 1, drops that dimension. Thus we preserve the dimension here.